# in laravel 5.2 , i need to create a form , i get the error like ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 1208: Method lable does not exist

Tags: php, html, forms

ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 1208:
Method lable does not exist.

i am using laravel 5.2 there it shows this error , i have searched many sites , but i have not what i needed . can any one help me

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Update</title>
</head>
<body>
 // {!! Form::open([ 'routes' => 'testing.update' ]) !!}
 // {{ Form::model($user,['method'=>'patch','action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]])}}

// <div class="form-group">
     // {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
     // {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
// </div>

// <div class="form-group">
     // {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    // {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 // </div>
// <div class="form-group">
    // {!! Form::label('mobile', 'Mobile:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    // {!! Form::text('mobile', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 // </div>
 // {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

 // {!! Form::close() !!}

     {{ Form::open([ 'routes' => 'testing.update' ]) }}

 {{ Form::model($user,['method'=>'patch','action'=>['testing@update',$user->id]])}}


 {{ Form::lable('name','Name')}}

{{ Form::text('name')}}
  {{ Form::lable('email','email')}}

  {{ Form::text('email')}}
 {{ Form::lable('mobile','mobile')}}

 {{ Form::text('mobile')}}
  <br/>
     {{ Form::submit("update")}}u    {{ Form::close()}}

</body>
</html>
```

here i used both 4.5 and 5.2 version format

Comment: Should it be `label` (note spelling)?

Comment: Thanks To Mr. Jim Garrison , what you said is correct and i done that once again i thanks